# Run parent jquery from iframe

Tags: jquery, class, iframe, click, title

I want that a class named "test" in the iframe can run a jquery code in the parent, I have tried the following, it does not work

Parent :

```
$("#listing").$(".test").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('title'));
  return false;
});
```

Iframe <iframe id="listing"> :

```
<a href="/89" title="hello" class="test">Click</a>
<a href="/90" title="hello2" class="test">Click</a>
```

What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Do you want code in your frame to use the jQuery library loaded in its parent document, or do you want code in the parent document to access the frame's contents?

Comment: I want it in the parent, thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("#listing").find(".test").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('title'));
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use contentWindow.document to access the iframe document.

```
$(document.getElementById('listing').contentWindow.document).find('.test').click(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method, in addition to its other uses, allows to access the content document of an `<iframe>` (provided, of course, it comes from the same domain as the parent, because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)):

```
$("#listing").contents().find(".test").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("title"));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: When does this code run? Anywhere other than a `load` handler is not reliable, as the frame contents may not have finished loading yet.

Comment: It is only 2 lines in the iframe, so there is no delay

Comment: So you're running this code right after setting the `src` attribute? It will not work, even if there is no noticeable delay, as the operations involved run orders of magnitude faster than a document load.

Comment: <script>
    $("#listing").contents().find(".test").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("title"));
        return false;
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe id="listing" src="test.html"></iframe>
     test.html :
    <a href="/89" title="hello" class="test">Click</a>
    <a href="/90" title="hello2" class="test">Click</a>

Thats all